# Does creating a new policy to enforce tagging in AWS resources affect resources that already been created

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am planning to create a policy that enforce tagging when creating an AWS resources. so when creating a new policy to enforce tagging in AWS resources affect resources that already been created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing resources don't get affected/deleted by the introduction of new protective/preventive IAM policies that prohibit creation of resources without tags. You can find existing resources that don't have tags with the use of AWS Resource Groups to find resources that have an empty value for a tag that your organization expects (EG. env, owner, project)